# JNLP Launching error

Tags: java, jnlp

I have jnlp application installed on remote client computer. Everyting was OK since today, when i without reinstall or restart tomcat server. The client pc gets following error:

```
com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: http://112.92.56.120:8080/CrownX/libs/axis2/axis2-transport-http-1.5.1.jar
 at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.downloadJarFiles(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.downloadEagerorAll(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.downloadResources(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareLaunchFile(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

java.io.IOException: index file not found
 at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry$9.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry.writeFileToDisk(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry.writeFileToDisk(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache.downloadResourceToTempFile(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache.downloadResourceToCache(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.downloadJarFiles(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.downloadEagerorAll(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.downloadResources(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareLaunchFile(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

When i tried downloading application from another pc everything is OK.
I reinstalled JRE, rebuild and restart server - no result.
Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is host 112.92.56.120 accessible tot he client on port 8080?

Comment: Error fixed! I clear java web start cache directory and resinstall!

Comment: Nice work NikolayGS. As a friendly reminder, can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer so that we can close this question? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.